# Hashing object hierarchy

Tags: javascript, json, algorithm, hash, traversal

Trying to implement my own object hierarchy hashing. Similar to [object-hash](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-hash), but simpler.

Requirements:

- support simple hierarchies of objects and arrays
- support various primitives, e.g. numbers, strings, boolean, etc
- unique hash ingest

Should be simple enough, but I'm struggling with the last requirement. Given an object e.g.

```json
{ a: { x: 'b' } }
```

we could hash this using [pre-order traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal) as

```js
crypto
  .createHash('sha1')
  .update('object')
  .update('a')
  .update('object')
  .update('x')
  .update('string')
  .update('b')
  .digest()
  .toString('base64')
// => CWrPyn7XLM4k/uDGnDCqqDv3Iy0=
```

However this would then yield the same hash as

```json
{ aobjectx: 'b' }
```

with

```js
crypto
  .createHash('sha1')
  .update('object')
  .update('aobjectx')
  .update('string')
  .update('b')
  .digest()
  .toString('base64')
// => CWrPyn7XLM4k/uDGnDCqqDv3Iy0=
```

We could use a separator and escape it everywhere, but that would require quite a bit of search and replace, so maybe there is a more efficient way.

If we combine pre and post-order it seems much harder to cause a collision this way. However I'm not sure that a collision can't still be constructed.

Using `JSON.stringify` would work, but I have performance concerns and it doesn't work well for edge cases, e.g. `undefined`.

I've looked at the [code](https://github.com/puleos/object-hash/blob/master/index.js) of object-hash, but am not sure if they're dealing with this problem.

Looking for suggestions to make this **workable** and **performant**. Ideally with some mathematical proof that shows a collision similar to above can't be constructed.

Thank you for you help!

Comment: One can *always* construct a collision to a hash, you just shouldn't be able to do it so easily.

Comment: @Bergi Absolutely. Just improved the wording in my question. The problem is that the hashing ingest is identical and that should not happen

Comment: You already *are* using a separator: `object`. Yes, you'd need to properly escape it, or use one that isn't as likely to appear as part of a value. And no, escaping doesn't require search-and-replace, just a split, and passing the individual parts to `update`.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you really just want this:

```
crypto.createHash('sha1').update(JSON.stringify({ a: { x: 'b' } })).digest().toString(base64)
```

That will perform better than anything else you'd write, BUT the keys in an object could come out in any order, so you could get different hashes for equivalent objects.

One way to fix that would be to transform every object (including lists) into a list so that you can sort the keys, like:

```
{b: 1, a: 2} -> ["O", "a", 2, "b", 1]
["a", 2, "b", 1] -> ["L", "a", 2, "b", 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Add some postfixes to your data, and the hash will be different:

```js
crypto
  .createHash('sha1')
  .update('object'+"#")
  .update('a'+"#")
  .update('object'+"#")
  .update('x'+"#")
  .update('string'+"#")
  .update('b'+"#")
  .digest()
  .toString('base64')
```

```js
crypto
  .createHash('sha1')
  .update('object'+"#")
  .update('aobjectx'+"#")
  .update('string'+"#")
  .update('b'+"#")
  .digest()
  .toString('base64')
```

Comment: But you can still easily construct a collision the same way. So this doesn't solve anything. Or am I missing something?

Comment: no, use a crazy nonsense postfix, that's it